# Can std::fill() throw when filling a vector of objects with a non-throwing copy-assignment operator?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have a vector of nothrow-default-constructible and nothrow-copy-assignable values, e.g. built-in types. We want to reset each element of the vector to its default value. Can we be sure that the following function will never throw an exception?

```cpp
template <typename T>
void resetVector(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_copy_assignable_v<T>);
    static_assert(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible_v<T>);

    std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), T{});
}
```

[C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) mentions exceptions only for the overload of `std::fill()` with an execution policy parameter. But what about the overload without an execution policy? Is there any reason for it to throw in this case?

Comment: maybe with static_assert(noexcept(std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), T{})));

Comment: @jls28 That would always return false, it's not marked `noexcept`.

Comment: `T{}` is a default construction and `fill` does copy assignment so as long as both of those operations are `noexcept` then there is nowhere in this code where an excpection can be thrown.